# Error signing in to Firebase with FlutterFlow

Tags: firebase, flutterflow

I have this error

`Could not sign in as firebase@flutterflow.io to your Firebase project. Make sure "Email Sign-In" is turned on for your Firebase project, and try again.`

I checked authentication and have firebase@flutterflow.io in, but when I try to connect to the database with FlutterFlow, it shows me that error.

Comment: *somebody can help me* is not a question, and *i have issue* is not a problem description, which means your entire title is meaningless. Please [edit] it to describe the problem you're having or actual question you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

This situation has been driving me up the wall for about 5 days, unfortunately, I couldn't find the answer after scouring the web for days!

It turns out you have to turn on authentication under Build in Firebase. Then enable email/password under the sign-in method tab!

Comment: This. Do note that this setting is located in the Firebase console, not the FlutterFlow UI.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not enough. On Firebase you have to add the mail 'firebase@flutterflow.io' with 'Editor' privileges under Project (Cog wheel) -> Users and permissions. Read more here: https://docs.rowy.io/integrations/flutterflow/setup

Answer (score 2):

Clicking in flutterflow (settings/firebase/"regenerate config files") resolved my issue. Everything else is done automatically other then enabling authentication of email/password signin in firebase.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Firebase console (console.firebase.google.com).
2. Select your project.
3. Navigate to "Project settings" by clicking on the gear icon in the top left corner.
4. In the "Project settings" page, go to the "Users and permissions" tab.
   Click on the "Add Member" button.
5. Enter "firebase@flutterflow.io" in the "Email address" field.
6. Select the role as "Editor" from the dropdown.
7. Click on the "Add" button to grant access.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by going to Firebase - Build/Authentication/Sign in Method (tab) - then chose email and password and turned login in from Email and password and this fixed the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnKzc.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to delete the user firebase@flutterflow.io from the user list in Authentication.

My project already existed and was configured, and I noticed that when trying to load the FlutterFlow Firestore Manager it was trying to register as a user in Firebase and since the project was configured the user firebase@flutterflow.io already existed, Firebase returning the following error:

```json
{
    "mistake": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid",
                "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS"
    }
}
```

By deleting the user firebase@flutterflow.io `FlutterFlow` was able to complete its "user" registration and the Firestore Data Manager was able to access the content of my Firestore with its editor permissions.